# Unable to set up Git pull in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We currently have Subversion builds in Jenkins, and are trying to add Git builds as well, using Windows filesystem access.

So far:

- Jenkins GIT Plugin is installed.
- Jenkins and the repositories are on the same machine, so we don't need ssh setup.
- Started a new Jenkins Project, and clicked on Git under Source Code Management.

We're hitting a snag on the Repsitory URL:

```
Repository URL: file:////my_server/Repositories/My_Repo
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h file:////my_server/Repositories/My_Repo HEAD
```

To troubleshoot, I created a separate project which just runs Windows commands, and confirmed that:

1. Jenkins has permission to see the repository
2. The Jenkins path can find git.exe
3. I can get output from Jenkins running `git ls-remote file:////my_server/Repositories/My_Repo`
4. Which means my URI format is correct

Does anyone know how to fix the error with the Jenkins Git plugin not being able to connect to the repository, when Jenkins itself can?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my file URI was correct, and even though my path variables were correct and included Git, Jenkins was unable to find it using the Windows path.

I resolve the problem by going to:

1. Manage Jenkins
2. Configure System
3. Git
4. Path to Git executable

And entering C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Well that would be because that's not a valid Git URI. You need to link to the C:\ or whatever drive letter path, not to a file:// url. Also, two slashes, not three.

Comment: It's a UNC path so there is no drive letter.

Comment: Mount the drive in Windows Explorer.

Comment: I've already told you I tested the repository path using a Windows command task.  Drive letter does not work from a Windows service.