# Unable to connect GIT repository to jenkins

Tags: git, maven, github, jenkins

I am trying to connect jenkins (installed on my windows os) to my github repository(which has a maven project). I have configured the maven, jdk and installed the github plugins; however, I am getting an error as I provide the git repository url:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command:  -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@github.com:saurabhxkapoor/seleniumcookbook.git HEAD
```

Though, I have already set up a user in jenkins, I am unable to figure out what could be the issue.
As such, the build fails.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/q/12681308/6309 help (similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21592263/6309)? Or https://github.com/wakaleo/jenkins-the-definitive-guide-book/issues/31#issuecomment-63366036?

Comment: thanks @VonC ..  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21592263/6309 helped me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to set up Git pull in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565569/unable-to-set-up-git-pull-in-jenkins)